# Does getTimezoneOffset change when you move timezones on a mobile browser

Tags: javascript, timezone-offset

When I am in Chicago using a mobile browser, and I get timezone offset of -360, for -6 hours. If I get on a plane and fly to San Fransisco, do I automatically see that adjusted to -480 for -8 hrs, without changing the timezone on the phone? That is does the clock pick up the timezone from the cell tower, and reset it in a way that the javascript engine knows?

Comment: Pretty sure this is specific to phone OS implementations.

Comment: Thanks Demian, if that is the case can you guys tell me what your experience is on specific phones? I'm guessing it might also depend on your carrier.

Comment: Sorry, when I say phones, what I really mean is OS/carrier combinations.